# HTML and custom field variable, inside variable

Tags: filters

I'm trying to get data from a custom field and then passing that into a variable which is then used to perform a function which is - adding the tweet in the body of the_content(); This code was initially meant for inserting ads into the_content(); thats why the function is named that, didn't bother changing name yet.

I can't get the actual custom field data to echo and finish the tweet intent with what user entered because I can't use echo inside a variable.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );

function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
  $tweet = get_field('tweet_msg');
  $tweet_intent = '<div style="margin-bottom:15px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="'.$tweet.'">TEST</a> </div>';

  if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
    return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $tweet_intent, 2, $content );
  }

  return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
  $closing_p = '</p>';
  $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
  foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

    if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {        $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
    }
    if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
      $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
    }
  }     return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```